# How do I retrieve available phone numbers in Nexmo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vonage

I want to retrieve all available phone voice phone numbers (Phone Numbers only) using a pattern search without all the parameters.

I have tried the api code given by nexmo.  It works, but I only get a limited amount of phone numbers and I am also getting a bunch of other parameters, I don't want.  here are the 2 api calls I am using:

```py
phnumbers = client.get_available_numbers("US", {"features": "VOICE"})
phnumbers = client.get_available_numbers("US", {"pattern": "007", "search_pattern": 2})
```

I just want to have a list of available numbers. I don;t care if it's 1000.  Not sure if there is a way to limit the number it brings back.  Currently getting a limited amount of number with parameters like the following:

```py
{'count': 394773, 'numbers': [{'country': 'US', 'msisdn': '12014790696', 'cost': '0.90', 'type': 'mobile-lvn', 'features': ['VOICE', 'SMS']}
```

That's one number.  I only want to tell it give me all the voice numbers and get them in a list...Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the docs and I don't think it's possible to only get the phone number (also called `msisdn`) back.

Instead, for each number, you'll get a thing which includes country, cost, type, etc... , part of, as the docs say, *"A paginated array of available numbers and their details"*.

If you look at the response, you can see that you get `count` as the first key/value pair, in your example the count is 394773, and this is the total count of numbers available for the search condition you specified when you made the request.

Now, I don't know all the reasons but to send back one response with a payload of 394773 numbers would probably be taxing too much the system.

What you can do:

---

From my tests, if you specify a `size` of 100, then you'll get a response with 100 records per page and you have the `index` parameter which you can use to paginate (anything above 100 for `size` and you get only 10 records).

So, if the count is 394773 for your search query, with `size = 100`, we have 3947 + 1 pages (the last page (`index = 3948`) only has 73 records) and you would have to get them one by one with a total of 3948 requests passing the appropriate index value.

Of course you can reduce the `count` if you pass a more specific search query.

I understand what you want, and I don't work for Nexmo, and again, after reading the docs I don't think it's possible to get everything back in just one request. You'll just need to be more specific in your search query.

Docs:

---

[Retrieve inbound numbers that are available for the specified country.](https://developer.nexmo.com/api/numbers#getAvailableNumbers)

Comment: Thank  You!  I am new to APIs.  Re-teaching myself programming.  I appreciate your help and I am thinking of creating a loop to request the 100 numbers like 10 times to get 1,0000 numbers at a time.  Thanks again for your help.